# swiftsuspenders constructor parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, dependency-injection, robotlegs, swiftsuspenders

Once I read in some google document about coding guidelines that every new instance of a class should go from a factory class, and I use SwiftSuspenders for it.

Now my question is, is it possible to create a new instance of an object that requires constructor parameters using SS's dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Swiftsuspenders fully supports constructor injection.

You can either inject into a field (or a method or another constructor) requiring an instance of your class, or you can use `injector.getInstance` to directly query the injector for an instance that's created using the injector's mappings.

Comment: Well, I think I don't understand. Can you get an instance of a class that requires parameter on construction and how would you do it? Can you post code example please. If I use injector.getInstance i get an error that I am missing a constructor parameter of course.

Comment: @MatejŠimunić If the constructor parameter is of a type which is mapped in the injector, it will be injected. Otherwise not, obviously.